# How to add country code with mobile number input field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to add country code in mobile number input field prefix. I have tried the below code.

```html
 <script>
   var telInput = $("#mobile"),
   errorMsg = $("#error-msg"),
   validMsg = $("#valid-msg");

   // initialise plugin
   telInput.intlTelInput({

   allowExtensions: true,
   formatOnDisplay: true,
   autoFormat: true,
   autoHideDialCode: true,
   autoPlaceholder: true,
   defaultCountry: "in",
   ipinfoToken: "yolo",

   nationalMode: false,
   numberType: "MOBILE",
   //onlyCountries: ['us', 'gb', 'ch', 'ca', 'do'],
   preferredCountries: ['sa', 'ae', 'qa','om','bh','kw','ma'],
   preventInvalidNumbers: true,
   separateDialCode: false,
   initialCountry: "in",
   geoIpLookup: function(callback) {
   $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function() {}, "jsonp").always(function(resp) {
     var countryCode = (resp && resp.country) ? resp.country : "";
     callback(countryCode);
    });
 },
    utilsScript: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.9/js/utils.js"
 });

 var reset = function() {
   telInput.removeClass("error");
   errorMsg.addClass("hide");
   validMsg.addClass("hide");
 };

 // on blur: validate
 telInput.blur(function() {
   reset();
   if ($.trim(telInput.val())) {
     if (telInput.intlTelInput("isValidNumber")) {
       validMsg.removeClass("hide");
     } else {
       telInput.addClass("error");
       errorMsg.removeClass("hide");
     }
   }
 });

 // on keyup / change flag: reset
 telInput.on("keyup change", reset);

</script>
```

I have tried and it is working. But I can submit mobile number without country code, and that should not be. The country code should not be editable.

I have used below js and css:

```xml
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.9/css/intlTelInput.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.9/js/intlTelInput.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.9/js/intlTelInput.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.9/js/utils.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a better and more flexible way to collect telephone numbers, in the form of an excellent [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input)

You can also play with a live  [demo here](https://intl-tel-input.com/)

[image]

**Usage is simple** make sure you’ve included jQuery, the library, and the CSS file, and that the flag sprite is available and properly referenced from the CSS – you’ll find it in **build/img/flags.png**

Next, create an element:

```
<input type="tel" id="number">
```

Finally, intialize it as follows:

```
$("#number").intlTelInput();
```

For a full list of configuration options, [consult the documentation.](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input)